# Hours of study for Vedas

Tags: vedas

Bhishma [says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a109.htm)

> Those Brahmanas that **never study the Vedas at hours not intended for study**, and that practise penances with devotion, succeed in overcoming all difficulties.

Which hours/days/times are intended and not intended for study of Vedas?

Comment: I think that is to be decided by the Guru under whom you study them. Plus, the time cannot be after sunset.